# Android GPS set location by calculation average

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

i have a class that implements LocationListener, so in the method onLocationChanged i get the current location once the gps gets the information.

My question is that i would like to save all coordinates that a want (for example 5 coordinates) in a list and calculate the average once i get the fifth coordinate and update the result as my location.

My only problem is how to set my calculated coordinate as my location. Do i have to use mock location or there is a better way?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I set the location manager in onCreate:

```
//GPS sensor
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);   

    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Log.d(TAG, "bestProvider: " + String.valueOf(bestProvider));

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 2000, 2, locationListener);
```

Here's the Listner:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        latitudeList.add(latitude);
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        longitudeList.add(longitude);
        altitude = location.getAltitude();
        altitudeList.add(altitude);

        Log.d(TAG, "latitude: " + String.valueOf(latitude));
        Log.d(TAG, "longitude: "+ String.valueOf(longitude));
        Log.d(TAG, " altitude " + String.valueOf(altitude));

        locationCounter++;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+locationCounter,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(locationCounter == COUNTERRESET){

            for(int i = 0; i < latitudeList.size();i++){
                latitudeAverage = latitudeAverage + latitudeList.get(i);
                longitudeAverage = longitudeAverage + longitudeList.get(i);
                altitudeAverage = altitudeAverage + altitudeList.get(i);
            }

            latitudeAverage = latitudeAverage / latitudeList.size();
            longitudeAverage = longitudeAverage / longitudeList.size();
            altitudeAverage = altitudeAverage / altitudeList.size();

            locationUpdate = new Location(bestProvider);
            location.setLatitude(latitudeAverage);
            location.setLongitude(longitudeAverage);
            location.setAltitude(altitudeAverage);

            **HERE I WANT TO SET LOCATION UPDATE AS MY GPS POSITION**

            locationCounter = 0;
            latitudeAverage = 0;
            longitudeAverage = 0;
            altitudeAverage = 0;
            latitudeList.clear();
            longitudeList.clear();
            altitudeList.clear();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i can't understand your question. What do you really want to ask?
Please be clear. If there is any error you are facing, post your code and logcat to have a look at

Comment: Just create a field myLocation, and use that, or call a method myLocationChanged() with the content of the averaging process. Most of your src then has to use myLocationChanged() instead the original onLocationChanged()